# Is magneto-optic Kerr effect discernible for material with natural optical activity?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, optical-materials

Magneto-optic Kerr effect requires a system with internal magnetism or external magnetic field and exhibits, say, circular dichroism for reflection measurements. Natural optical activity can have similar effects without any magnetism.

Consider such a magnetic system with also natural optical activity (e.g., a chiral material). Then it seems that the Kerr signal should come from both the magnetic Kerr and also the natural activity. How can one make sure where the signal comes from or separate different contributions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have access to this paper via university:
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/33/3/307/pdf
Equation (3.9) will yield the fields you want to calculate.
In this paper the matrix without field is assumed to be diagonal and containing only kappa_l. This assumption does not hold in your case, and you have to make the corresponding adjustments.

With some math you will eventually end up with equation (4.26), with the input of (4.12). The latter has to be adjusted.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I don’t see how the natural optical activity enters or can be separated?

Comment: you should change kappa_l (dielectric constant). it is assumed that without the magnetic field, the material has a constant kappa_l, proportional to unity. you will have to make it a matrix with off-diagonal constants.